# Gin Validation for optional pointer to be uuid?

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

I have this struct

```
// CreateAccount Create Account Data Args
type CreateAccount struct {
    ....
    RegistrationID string  `example:"2c45e4ec-26e0-4043-86e4-c15b9cf985a2" json:"registration_id" binding:"max=63"`
    ParentID       *string `example:"7c45e4ec-26e0-4043-86e4-c15b9cf985a7" json:"parent_id" format:"uuid"`
}
```

ParentID is a pointer, and it is optional. But if it is provided, it should be uuid.

```
var params helper.CreateAccount
if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&params); err != nil {
...
}
```

if add this to ParentID  `binding:"uuid"`, it makes ParentID a required filed! Which is not the case here. If and only if ParentID is given, it should be uuid. Is there anyway to set it up this way.

Comment: have you tried using omitempty?

Comment: Yea, if i use it like this `json:"parent_id,omitempty"`, there is no uuid validation for ParentID. And if I add it like this `json:"parent_id,omitempty"  binding:"uuid"`, it does the uuid validation. But, it makes ParentID a required filed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to place the `omitempty` tag first.

```
type CreateAccount struct {
    ....
    RegistrationID string  `json:"registration_id" binding:"max=63"`
    ParentID       *string `json:"parent_id" binding:"omitempty,uuid"`
}
```

From the [validator docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10):

> Allows conditional validation, for example if a field is not set with a value (Determined by the "required" validator) **then other validation such as min or max won't run**

The way I read this sentence is that `omitempty` has to be placed before others, so that it can stop the validator chain if the value is not equal to the zero value.